Is there an analytic continuation of the Legendre Chi function $\chi_2(z)$ for $z > 1$?
The Legendre Chi function $\chi_2(z)$ is define as
$$
\chi_2(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}
$$
for $-1 \le z \le 1$. But $z > 1$ the series diverges. For real value of $z$ is there a convergent function $f(z)$ which is increasing and convergent for $z >1$ such that the definition of $f(z)$ coincides with the above definition of $\chi_2(z)$ in $-1 \le z \le 1$. Basically I am looking for an analytic continuation of $\chi_2(z)$ for real $z > 1$.

By the harmonic series
$$
\chi_2'(1) = \chi_2'(-1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1} = \infty,
$$
there are vertical asymptotes on the radius of convergence, so the answer seems to be no. But there is one on the complex plane according to this functional equation from Wikipedia:
$$
\chi_2(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{i \pi}{2} \ln|x| - \chi_2(1/x).
$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\chi_2(z)=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}&=\sum_{k\geq 0}\int_0^z \frac{y^{2k}}{(2k+1)}\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0}\int_0^z \frac{1}{y}\int_0^yx^{2k}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\
&\overset{(\ast)}{=}\int_0^z \frac{1}{y}\int_0^y\frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^z \frac{1}{y}\ln\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^z \frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}-\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{Li_2}(-z)-\mathrm{Li_2}(z)}{2},
\end{aligned}$$
where we assumed integral and summation are interchangeable and we also used the geometric series at $(\ast)$.
